# diskpart batch file script is not working from same folder in windows 8.1

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a batch file to hide an unhide a volume(drive).
when i ran it on my Desktop(windows 7) it worked from same folder(batch file and diskpart script in the same folder)
but in my laptop(windows 8.1) it not worked from the same folder.
but when i put the script file in "System32" folder it worked.
how can i fix this problem?
batch file

```
@echo on
echo to hide type y or to unhide type n
set /p comm=hide or unhide
if not y==%comm% goto unhide
:hide
diskpart /s hide.txt
pause
exit
:unhide
diskpart /s unhide.txt
pause
```

hide.txt

```
 sel vol 7
 remove letter H:
 exit
```

unhide.txt

```
sel vol 7
assign
exit
```

when i run it from the same folder it shows

> Microsoft DiskPart version 6.3.9600
>
> Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation. On computer: BHARGAB-PC
>
> DiskPart was unable to open or read the script file. Make sure the
>   file you specified exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarily put this line at the top of your bat file:

```
echo cd=%cd%
```

Did you 'Run as administrator' on 8.1? If so, that changes the current directory. You may see that the current directory is not what you expected. To solve this problem put the following line near the top of your bat file:

```
pushd %~dp0
```

Comment: Can I give inputs in diskpart script file?

Comment: I think you can. I haven't used the script file for diskpart though. Good info here http://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html