# Batch file - Switch USB from read/write to read-only and vice versa

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering if you can write a Batch file to make a USB from read/write to read-only and visa versa?

What the program should do is, if you double click on the batch file it searches for the USB drive, check if it is read/write or just read-only then swaps it to the other setting.

*EDIT*
I know the name of the USB and also the drive letter.
*EDIT*

I need this for work where we use USB drives to install programs on peoples laptops, we used CD's before, but they get lost inside.

Code would be appreciated, but directions to sites will help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and works flawlessly with the 4 drives I have tested.

I have the below for you if you would like. It requires 3 files though. The batch then 1 text file per each Read only or Read Write command. Simple setup but requires you to have an input, it will overwrite what ever it currently is to what ever you select.

Thanks JBin for advising that it needs to be run as Administrator, I forgot that was a thing.

```
cls
@Echo OFF
@Echo Toggle between read only and Read write
:choice
set /P c=Change to [R]ead Only or Read/[W]rite?
if /I "%c%" EQU "R" goto :read
if /I "%c%" EQU "W" goto :write

:read
DISKPART /s Readonly.txt
cls
@Echo  -----------------------
@Echo ^| Disk is now READ ONLY ^|
@Echo  -----------------------
@Echo.
goto :choice

:write
DISKPART /s Readwrite.txt
cls
@Echo  ------------------------
@Echo ^| Disk is now READ WRITE ^|
@Echo  ------------------------
@Echo.
goto :choice
```

Make two text files with the below in them. Name them what ever you like but dont forget to change the *.txt in the batch. This is also assuming you only have 1 usb device plugged into the computer

Readonly.txt file:

```
Sel disk 1
att dis set readonly
exit
```

Readwrite.txt file:

```
sel disk 1
att dis clear readonly
exit
```

Comment: OK I've tested it, but nothing is really happening. This is what I get: http://imgur.com/13aTU5u

Comment: And both of the files are in the same location as the BAT file. Spelled correctly and everything as you said.

Comment: Send a screenshot of the location, filenames and text file contents. Also did you modify the batch at all?

Comment: Mine seems to be working fine. Open CMD, type DISKPART > LIST DIS. If there is only 1 USB in then is should only show Disk 0 and Disk 1 (disk 1 being the USB). http://i.imgur.com/VcNdPfD.png

Comment: Exactly the same, only Disk 0 and Disk 1 where Disk 1 is the USB. http://imgur.com/NXie5b8

Comment: Still nothing. I put it just below @Echo OFF

Comment: Had a search around and it looks like someone did something similar. Sorry I could not be of more help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436569/diskpart-batch-file-script-is-not-working-from-same-folder-in-windows-8-1

Comment: Actually that helped... your code works perfectly, the only thing is the BAT file needs to be run in administrative mode. So just edit your answer to say that you must run it in ADMIN then I'll set your answer as the correct one, thank you very much

Comment: If you want to run a BAT file automatically do the following: Create a shortcut of the BAT file then right click the shortcut > shortcut TAB > Advanced... > Run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this is Batch (via Diskpart command), but it will be VERY convoluted.

Anyways, this code detects removable drives (so floppies, I think, are included), creates a menu, then swaps the setting (read-only/read-write). It makes flash drives "write-protected", but I tested my code...

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::Detect removable drives using DiskPart...
set "diskcnt=0"
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%A in (
   '^(echo list disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /ic:"Online"'
) do (
   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%X in (
      '^(echo select disk %%B^&echo detail disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /ic:"Removable"'
   ) do (
      set /a diskcnt+=1
      set "vol!diskcnt!=%%B_%%Z:"
   )
)


::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::After detecting drives, print a menu...

echo.The script detected %diskcnt% removable drive/s:
echo.
if %diskcnt% equ 0 echo No drives found.
for /l %%X in (1,1,%diskcnt%) do (
   echo.     %%X. Drive !vol%%X:~2,2!
)
echo.
:choice_loop
set /p "choice=Choose a Number: "
if !choice! geq 1 if !choice! leq %diskcnt% goto :doIt
goto choice_loop


::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::Get and set the setting...
:doIt
echo.
set "disknum=!vol%choice%:~0,1!"
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%F in (
   '^(echo select disk %disknum%^&echo attribute disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /bic:"Read-Only"'
) do (
   set "ro_state=%%G"&set "ro_state=!ro_state: =!"
)
if /i "%ro_state%" equ "No" (
   (echo select disk %disknum%&echo attribute disk set readonly)|diskpart >nul
   echo Drive !vol%choice%:~2,2! is now read-only from being read/write.
) else (
   (echo select disk %disknum%&echo attribute disk clear readonly)|diskpart >nul
   echo Drive !vol%choice%:~2,2! is now read/write from being read-only.
)
endlocal
pause
```

**EDIT:** My only concern here is that this is language dependent, so this will not work if the language is not English.

**EDIT #2:** Forgive me from misunderstanding the problem. If you already have a USB name to be modified, then try this: (Make sure there are no 2 flash drives with the same name that are plugged in at the same time.)

```
@echo off

::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::Put the name of flash drive here... (Case-sensitive)
set "name=[PUT NAME HERE]"

::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::Detect that removable drive using DiskPart...
set "disk_num="
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%A in (
   '^(echo list disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /ic:"Online"'
) do (
   for /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%W in (
      '^(echo select disk %%B^&echo detail disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /ic:"Removable"'
   ) do (
      if "%%Z"=="%name%" set "disk_num=%%B"
   )
)
if not defined disk_num (
   echo Flash drive '%name%' not found.
   goto end_this
)

::~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
::Get and set the setting...
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=: " %%F in (
   '^(echo select disk %disk_num%^&echo attribute disk^)^|diskpart^|findstr /bic:"Read-Only"'
) do (
   set "ro_state=%%G"
)

if /i "%ro_state%" equ "No" (
   (echo select disk %disk_num%&echo attribute disk set readonly)|diskpart >nul
   echo Flash drive '%name%' is now read-only from being read/write.
) else (
   (echo select disk %disk_num%&echo attribute disk clear readonly)|diskpart >nul
   echo Flash drive '%name%' is now read/write from being read-only.
)

:end_this
pause
exit /b
```

**EDIT #3:** For Windows 8 and up, Run the Batch Files as Administrator for this to work.

Comment: It opens Diskpart, but what should I do when it opens?

Comment: Wait can't I just search the USB by finding it's name, because I know what the device's name will be.

Comment: Plus I know what the drive letter would be, I'll edit my Questioin

Comment: @JBin So it does not work?  The output must be like at the link: http://i.imgur.com/OMu4OHW.jpg